# spring-data-mongodb dependency for @Aggregation annotation for aggregation pipeline

Tags: java, maven, pipeline, aggregation, spring-data-mongodb

```java
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Aggregation;
```

Following import is not resolved for

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
   <version>3.4.15</version>
</dependency>
```

but my production uses 1.9.3.RELEASE

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/Aggregation.html) the annotation interface `@Aggregation` exists since version 2.2.

So it seems you can't use within `1.9.3.RELEASE` version.